# MVC3 custom Html helper

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

I want to create a custom datagrid helper using asp.net mvc3 . I want to pass an array of strings to it and I want that if i call it like this:

```
@Html.grid(myarray)
```

It render as table with each row having array value. Please suggest solution to it.

Thanks

Comment: The chances that somebody will do all the work for you is not very likely, I would suggest you try and do it and when you get stuck change the question to where your problem is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the thing you are looking for:

[MvcContrib's Grid](http://www.jeremyskinner.co.uk/2009/02/23/rewriting-the-mvccontrib-grid-part-3-gridmodels-and-gridrenderers/)

Comment: While this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.